# Changing width doesn't take effect

Tags: qt, qml

I have the follow toggle switch:

[image: Toggle switch with label]

Developed by this QML code

```
        Row {
            id: myToggle
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: 270
            height: 25

            StyledLabel {
                id: myToggleLabel
                text: qsTr("Toggle")
                width: parent.width - myToggleSwitch.width
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }

            Switch {
                id: myToggleSwitch
                height: parent.height
                implicitWidth: parent.width * 0.25 // changing 0.25 to 0.5
                                                   // or 0.75 or ...
                                                   // doesn't have any effect
                // Also replacing "implicitWidth" with "width" doesn't help!

                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                checked: true
                onCheckedChanged: { console.log("checked: ", checked) }
            }
        }
```

I intend to change how much of row width is occupied by `label` and how much row width is occupied by `switch` itself.

I change the `0.25` value in the code to `0.5` or `0.75` or ... but it has no effect. Does anybody know why?

Comment: never anchor horizontally in a `row` or vertically in a `column`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting **anchors** was interfering with setting **width**.

Removing this line off of `Switch` with ID `id: myToggleSwitch` solved the problem:

```
anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
```

Now the switch width can be adjusted:

[image: Toggle switch solved]